# Driver won't change material color

Tags: drivers

[image]
Hi,

I copied the driver from the x-axis of the location of the object to(pasted it in) the r value in the rgb  color component of the base color of the material. When I move the cube around maually with "G", I see the object change color.
[image]

But when I animate the scene: the cube has rigid body aspects, active and convex settings;
the plane has rigid body aspects, passive and mesh settings
and the force field pushes the cube to the side, I can't see it change color.
thx

Comment: Can you upload your blender file (or better yet, the simplest example reproducing the problem) to https://blend-exchange.com/ ? Can you paste the driver properties into your question?

Comment: The physics XYZ is not the same as regular XYZ. You may have to look into Delta transformations.

Comment: Thx for the feedback, I'll repost if I need more help